# AngularJs decoding HTML characters (unwanted)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding

I want to pass data from HTML to AngularJs. That's working fine:

```
<div ng-init='initModel(@Model.ToJson())'></div>
```

Actual HTML:

```
    <div ng-init='initModel({
      ...
        "description": "<pre><code>&lt;script&gt;alert(\"test\");&lt;/script&gt;\n</code></pre>",
        "title": "tes testse stsets sets"
      }
    },
    ...
})'></div>
```

The description is correctly encoded. The <pre> and <code> elements are not encoded, this is trusted HTML. The <script> tag is encoded.

In my AngularJs controller I have this function:

```
$scope.initModel = function(model) {
   $scope.data = model.response.data;
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in this function, output of model is:

```
"<pre><code><script>alert("test");</script>↵</code></pre>"
```

It looks like AngularJs decodes all HTML characters by executing this initModel() function, but why? I would like to have the same encoding as it is rendered in the HTML.

Some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use ngBindHtml https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: I'm already using ngBindHtml, but the problem is that the <script> tag also will be executed. I don't want the encoded HTML characters to be executed as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the ToJson() function:

```
public static class JsonHelpers
    {
        public static IHtmlString ToJson<T>(this T obj)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
            };
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings));
        }
    }
```

changing to:

```
public static class JsonHelpers
{
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
    }
}
```

solved the problem.